# r plot xlab for side 3 and side 4

Tags: r, plot, r-base-graphics

In `R` is there a way to have titles for side 3 (top) = x2 and side 4 (right) = y2  like highlighted below?

Below is `R` code.

```
x<-1:4; y=x*x
  
plot(x, y, pch=18, col="red", type="b",
     frame=FALSE, xaxt="n") # Remove x axis
axis(1, 1:4, LETTERS[1:4], col.axis="blue")
axis(3, col = "darkgreen", lty = 2, lwd = 0.5)
axis(4, col = "violet", col.axis = "dark violet", lwd = 2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add labels to additional axes using `mtext()`. For the right `y` axis you will probably need to add extra space using `par(mar = ...)`

```r
par(mar = c(5, 4, 4, 5)) # create extra space for label
plot(1:5)
axis(3)
axis(4)
mtext("top xaxis", side = 3, line = 2)
mtext("right y axis needs extra space", side = 4, line = 2)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-11-08 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>